# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}}$

Tags: limits

What would be an easy way to evaluate 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0}{{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0}} 
$$

where $a_n,b_n \neq 0 $

Comment: Are the coefficients non-zero?

Comment: Nearly 4 years on the site and you post this?

Comment: @mvw : updated the question

Comment: @Did : Just realized how simple it really is, apologies for elementary question, not having a sharp moment.

Comment: The simplicity of the question is not the issue. That you deliberately flout every howtoask guideline available on this site is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^n$ and then take the limit!